# Python Pipe and write the out to a separate file

Tags: python

I'm new to python and trying to use this on multi nodes, cloud.
cmd2 is running another python program to take stdin to stdout. 
cmd1 should be "cat filename" for the input of cmd2.

```
cmd1 = 'cat ./filename'
cmd2 = 'python stdin2out.py'

p=pipes.Template()
p.append (cmd, '--')
p.append (cmd2, '--')
```

// THIS IS THE PART confusing to me

```
t=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('r')
f=p.open(t.name, 'r')
for l in f.readlines():
    print l 
f.close()
```

Does the above for loop run the piped command and take the output to stdout?